# Eclipse isn't picking up dependencies in user entries classpath of run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-classpath

I have my application project and all its dependencies as part of "user entries" in Run configuration. The bootstrap entries contain JRE.

Despite this, my application isn't running because of classpath issues. I see that duplicating jars from user entries to bootstrap entries works. But I cannot do this since my app has a lot of dependent jars. I cannot move large number of jars from user entries to boot strap entries. How do I make sure the run time environment has all the required jars?

Comment: If you have many dependencies, think about using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: I am using maven already. The dependencies have been brought to my system by maven.